# splitting mongo custom-converters into multiple context files?

Tags: spring, spring-data

This is my configuration :

```
    <org.springframework.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <spring.data.mongo.version>1.0.0.RC1</spring.data.mongo.version>
```

Is it possible to split from this 1 spring context file :

```
<mongo:mapping-converter base-package="my.package.converter">
    <mongo:custom-converters>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="my.package.converter.ClassAbcReadConverter" />
        </mongo:converter>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="my.package.converter.ClassAbcWriteConverter" />
        </mongo:converter>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="my.package.converter.subpackage.ClassDefReadConverter" />
        </mongo:converter>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="my.package.converter.subpackage.ClassDefWriteConverter" />
        </mongo:converter>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="my.package.converter.subpackage.ClassGhiWriteConverter" />
        </mongo:converter>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="my.package.converter.subpackage.ClassGhiReadConverter" />
        </mongo:converter>
    </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>
```

into 2 spring context files (in different maven modules) like these below ?

file1-context.xml

```
<mongo:mapping-converter base-package="my.package.converter">
    <mongo:custom-converters>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="my.package.converter.ClassAbcReadConverter" />
        </mongo:converter>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="my.package.converter.ClassAbcWriteConverter" />
        </mongo:converter>
    </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>
```

file2-context.xml

```
<mongo:mapping-converter base-package="my.package.converter">
    <mongo:custom-converters>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="my.package.converter.subpackage.ClassDefReadConverter" />
        </mongo:converter>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="my.package.converter.subpackage.ClassDefWriteConverter" />
        </mongo:converter>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="my.package.converter.subpackage.ClassGhiWriteConverter" />
        </mongo:converter>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="my.package.converter.subpackage.ClassGhiReadConverter" />
        </mongo:converter>
    </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>
```

Is there any helpful attributes for 'merging' for mongo converters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `custom-converters` element actually has a `base-package` attribute as well which will trigger the listed packages to be scanned for `Converter` and `GenericConverter` implementations. The one you were using at the `mapping-converter` level is to pickup domain classes on startup. So you should be fine by simply removing the explicitly defined converter beans and adding the additional attribute.

```
<mongo:mapping-converter base-package="my.package.entities">
  <mongo:custom-converters base-package="my.package.converters" />
</mongo:mapping-converter>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips ! Could you point out the documentation on "pickup domain classes on startup" ? I would like to understand more on that statement. I am also curious whether "my.package.*.converters" would work.

Comment: `base-package` on the `mapping-converter` scans the configured package for classes annotated with `@Document` to avoid the mapping metadata to be scanned on first lookup at the `MappingContext`. Yes, the classpath scanning supports wildcards. I updated https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-384 to update the reference documentation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet the same problem, if configuring as:

```
<mongo:mapping-converter>
    <mongo:custom-converters>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="com.abc.converter.mongo.DBObjectToDateTime" />
        </mongo:converter>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="com.abc.converter.mongo.DateTimeToDBObject" />
        </mongo:converter>
    </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>
```

it works fine.
if configuring as:

```
<mongo:mapping-converter base-package="com.abc.*.entities">
    <mongo:custom-converters base-package="com.abc.converter.mongo" />
</mongo:mapping-converter>
```

the converters are not applied. 
the pagckage com.abc.*.entities has the @Document annotated class as well as @Entity annotated class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mongo:mapping-converter base-package="my.package.entities">
  <mongo:custom-converters base-package="my.package.converters" />
</mongo:mapping-converter>
```

wont't work in 1.1.0.RELEASE. If you take a look at the XSD file, only mongo:mapping-converter and converter define base-package. So you still need to do this.

```
<mongo:mapping-converter base-package="my.package.entities">
    <mongo:custom-converters>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="my.package.converters.DBObjectToDateTime" />
        </mongo:converter>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="my.package.converters.DateTimeToDBObject" />
        </mongo:converter>
    </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>
```

I didn't try if :

```
<mongo:mapping-converter base-package="my.package.entities">
    <mongo:custom-converters>
        <mongo:converter base-package="my.package.converters.DBObjectToDateTime" />
    </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>
```

would register all the converters. It doesn't seem to make sense and the maintainers suggestion would be better if it was implemented correctly.